# How to call a Java controller class from angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs

I have a web project..no service call but have a Java controller in which one of the method is returning a string.. this needs to be read in my js file.. I am not able to fetch the data or hit the url mapped to the controller class..

The controller class is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {    

    @GET        
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/details")
    public @ResponseBody String getUserDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("1");
        UserInfoDTO userInfoDTO = new UserInfoDTO();

        userInfoDTO.setUserName("Akriti");
        userInfoDTO.setUserId("1111");
        String userString = new Gson().toJson(userInfoDTO);
        //return new ModelAndView("index.jsp", "userString", userString);
        System.out.println("user" + userString);
        return userString;
    }
```

And the js file which i am using is:

```
'use strict';
(function () {
    /**
     * @ngdoc overview
     * @name User Module
     * @description Logged in User
     */
    var user = angular.module('sol.user', []);
    user.controller('sol.user.UserController', UserController);
    alert("Hi");
   // $state.go('home.user');
   function UserController($scope, $http){
       alert("Hello");
       $http({method: 'GET',
            url: '/user/details'})
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.profiles = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                  $scope.profiles = data;
                alert( "failure");
                alert( data);
            });
       $state.go('home.user');
   }
})();
```

The url is not getting triggered at all since none of system out statements are getting printed in the console.Please help

Comment: Which application server runs your Java? Which Java server technology? Is the GET URL callable via Browser?

Comment: Note that for the webapp, usually the URL is preceded by the application name, but that the browser ignores that. So, maybe your server is awaiting request to http://myserver/myapp/users/details and the browser is sending them to http://myserver/users/details. Check via the developer tools of the browsers the actual URL being queried.

Comment: I am expecting there to be another part of the URL that you're missing, before the /user part of the mapping. Check in the web.xml for a servlet-mapping or look for a class that extends Application and has an annotation 'ApplicationPath' on it.

Comment: Is your .class file created properly ..??
For your controller.??

Comment: yes .class file is getting generated

Comment: @AkritiPrasad you can use `@RestController` agains `Controller` this will return json. Do you try trigged your url using postman or curl for check webserver is working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code and open firebug network panel(or an equivalent replacement) and check if you find a network xhr call going to the url?

```
'use strict';
(function () {
    /**
     * @ngdoc overview
     * @name User Module
     * @description Logged in User
     */
    var user = angular.module('sol.user', []).controller('UserController',['$scope',$http','$state',function(scope,http,state){
        alert("Hello");
       http({method: 'GET',
            url: '/user/details'})
            .success(function(data) {
                scope.profiles = data;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                  scope.profiles = data;
                alert( "failure");
                alert( data);
            });
       state.go('home.user');
    }]);

})();
```